# Update parent React component when property changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a small React project with a Modal dialog that is a detailed view of my main page. Both the dialog and the main page have a like button that when I click on from the modal dialog, once I am out of the dialog, I want to see it clicked in the main site as well.

This is the component that is part of my modal dialog.

```
export const DialogPreview: React.FC<DialogPreviewProps> = ({ dialogInfo, isLiked }) => {
    const styles = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <div className={styles.body}>
                <div>
                    <DialogBody dialogInfo={dialogInfo} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Interactions isLiked={isLiked}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is the footer of the card component that renders in the main site:

```
export const VideoCardFooter: React.FC<VideoCardFooterProps> = ({
    isLiked,
}) => {
    return (
        <VideoCardFooter>
            <Interactions isLiked={isLiked}/>
        </VideoCardFooter>
    );
};
```

This is how the Interactions component looks like:

```
export const Interactions: React.FC<InteractionsProps> = ({ isLiked }) => {
    const LikedIcon = bundleIcon(ThumbLikeFilled, ThumbLikeRegular);

    const [fillIcon, setFill] = React.useState(isLiked);
    const iconStyleProps: FluentIconsProps = {
        filled: iconFilled
    }
    
    return (
            <Button icon={<LikedIcon  {...iconStyleProps}/> } onClick={() => { setIconColor(setFill === false? true : false); }} />
    );
};
```

When I execute the Interactions component from DialogPreview component, after I get out of the dialog, the component in the VideoCard is not updated. Is there a way that the like button updates when the button is clicked from the dialog?

Comment: Please share the parent component and child component code separately. So you can get quick answers

Comment: Pass a callback from parent to child and when clicked in child execute that callback to whatever you want to do inside the parent ui

Answer (score 0):

When you make a change in `Interactions` component, you have to change the state `isLiked` as well so that `isLiked` state in `Intercations` component inside of `VideoCardFooter` can recognize its change. Send `setIsLiked` function to `Interactions` with props and set the value to true when it is clicked.

If the component structure is getting too complicated with unnecessary props in component, [consider using context API](https://dev.to/andrzejewsky/how-to-get-rid-of-unnecessary-props-in-react-js-13pj).

Comment: How do I send a `setIsLiked` function to `Interactions`? I guess you are refering to do something like `<Interactions isLiked={isLiked}/ onLikedClick={()=>setIsLiked(!isLiked)}>` but typescript complains about the `setIsLiked`. I guess I am not sure how to send that.

Comment: Where is 'isLiked' state defined? (ex: `[isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false)`). From the parent components where it was defined, you have to send down to your child components.